# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL -

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to access s3 object url via lambda and I am getting following exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://rvs-rta-beta-na.s3.amazonaws.com/Jul-8018/eBooks/eBooksASINReport-EGFUS-SimpleHeader-P94M5TAN9BAYJX0W0FQ1-xls_99c13329-efa7-4084-ab70-5912a652316a_aggregatedLogs.csv: java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://rvs-rta-beta-na.s3.amazonaws.com/Jul-8018/eBooks/eBooksASINReport-EGFUS-SimpleHeader-P94M5TAN9BAYJX0W0FQ1-xls_99c13329-efa7-4084-ab70-5912a652316a_aggregatedLogs.csv
    at com.amazon.metricadapterslambda.lambda.functions.ProcessRVSResults.ProcessRVSResultsHandler.handleRequest(ProcessRVSResultsHandler.java:187)
    at com.amazon.metricadapterslambda.lambda.functions.ProcessRVSResults.ProcessRVSResultsLambda.handleRequest(ProcessRVSResultsLambda.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/test-123/abc/FILE_NAME.csv
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.amazon.metricadapterslambda.lambda.functions.ProcessRVSResults.ProcessRVSResultsHandler.getFailedRowDetailsFromRVS(ProcessRVSResultsHandler.java:204)
    at com.amazon.metricadapterslambda.lambda.functions.ProcessRVSResults.ProcessRVSResultsHandler.handleRequest(ProcessRVSResultsHandler.java:149)
    ... 5 more
```

Bucket Policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTNuMBER:role/LAMBDAROLE"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:-

Trying to open the link using bufferedReader

```
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))
```

Comment: The exception suggests that you are getting an `Access Denied` error. Can you possibly edit your question to show the line of code that is generating the error? Have you turned off S3 Block Public Access enough to allow the Bucket Policy to grant access?

Comment: Try using the S3 client to get the object from the bucket. If you just use `url.openStream()`, it won't add in the authentication headers that the S3 client will do automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to how Lambdas assume roles and obtain temporary session token.

Check this article on how to allow a specific role to access S3 objects. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-i-locked-the-whole-company-out-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket-1781de51e4be

Also make sure that your function has access to the S3  bucket itself (in addition to its objects)

Best,
Stefan